# Set submit button to another when clicking enter

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to set the submit button in an `ASP.NET` website to another submit button when clicking enter key on the keyboard. I've so far accomplished to do so, but problem is it still sends the second submit button too. I tried returning false in the `onkeypress` event in the `input` elements, but then it won't let me write anything to the text `input` boxes..

This is my javascript function:

```
function button_click() {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("msSend").focus();
        document.getElementById("msSend").click();
    }
}
```

And a sample text `input` box:

```
<input type="text" id="msname" name="msname" runat="server" onkeypress="button_click()" /></td>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps if you show the rendered HTML and WHY you do not want to click the other button?

Comment: I have one form for the whole website in my masterpage for some several reasons, so the button it always submits to is the login button.. So I want in several textboxes to submit to another button.

Comment: @mplungjan I just checked it, and it clicks some menu button that has nothing to do with a `submit` button. How do I prevent it? `<button name="bmenu" onclick="DisableHL('bmenu'); location.href='<%= movies %>'; return false;" class="btn">Movies</button>`

Comment: Please delete answer and question then. It is not likely useful to anyone other than yourself

Comment: Others might get this problem too..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I had some buttons in my `MasterPage` that was for some reason defined as `type="submit"`.
I changed:

```
<button name="bmenu" onclick="DisableHL('bmenu'); location.href='<%= movies %>'; return false;" class="btn">סרטים</button>
```

to:

```
<button name="bmenu" onclick="DisableHL('bmenu'); location.href='<%= movies %>'; return false;" class="btn" type="button">סרטים</button>
```

And there it fixed it! ;)